# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD(“newpass”)'

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, password, mysql

I'm using Mysql 8.0.12 version and I am currently facing a problem and I can't solve it even with the references around the internet. I have this error on phpmyadmin . By the I'm using High Sierra 10.13

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD("newpass")' at line 1

[image]

I tried this command on the terminal

```
 sudo /user/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

then entered my password and then

```
use mysql;

update user set authentication_String = PASSWORD("newpass") where user='root';
```

then tried this also

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
```

and lastly this

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("newpass") WHERE User='root';
```

But they all gave me the same error

Could someone please help me out . I'm stuck here.

Comment: Does https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html help?

Comment: @nohillside . How to do it in Mac sir ? And I'm using 8.0.12 version of mysql

Comment: The instructions for 8.x are the same, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html, the part in "B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems"

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you were using was close. It should be:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD') WHERE USER='root';
```

However you don't need to directly edit the `mysql` tables, rather use the dedicated commands:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD';
```

Note that the manual says that the syntax below is 'preferred' without hinting why you might choose one over the other:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD';
```